# Syncing Google Sheets with a database

Tags: c#, python, node.js, google-api, google-sheets-api

Does anyone know if there is a way to have google sheets run from a database like Oracle, Microsoft SQL, etc.? When the values in the database table(s) are updated, the spreadsheet will show those changes the next time it's opened. Also, possibly writing back to the DB. Is this possible? Any suggestions?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc) to connect to external database through [JDBC Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/jdbc).

> In Apps Script, the JDBC service supports [Google Cloud SQL](https://developers.google.com/sql/),
>   MySQL, Microsoft SQL Server, and Oracle databases.

Just follow the procedure specified in the documentation.

There is also a provided [sample](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc#sample_code) on how to:

- [Create a database, user, and table](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc#create_a_database_user_and_table)
- [Write to the database](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc#write_to_the_database)
- [Read from the database](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc#read_from_the_database)

Answer (score 1):

I've had trouble with this before so I built a solution in case you don't want to roll your own. [SeekWell](https://seekwell.io/) lets you automatically send data from SQL to Sheets and can also sync changes from Sheets back to a database. Apps Script can do pieces of this, but I found it buggy and limited for our use case, so built something else. There are both free and paid plans.